# Как единожды инициализировать сокет, и использовать его для нескольких подключений?

Tags: c#, .net, сокет

Как единожды инициализировать сокет, и использовать его для нескольких последовательных подключений к разным серверам без повторной инициализации?

Основная проблема в том, что после вызова `Socket.Disconnect(true)` и попытке подключиться к другому серверу синхронно - вываливается исключение:

> System.InvalidOperationException: После отключения сокета возможно
>   только повторное асинхронное подключение и только к другой конечной
>   точке EndPoint.  Необходимо вызвать метод BeginConnect для потока,
>   выход из которого не произойдет до завершения операции.

p.s. асинхронно удается подключиться, все работает нормально, как и написано в тексте исключения. Можно ли как то поменять поведение сокета для синхронных запросов?